# Implementing a long press to share button in android

Tags: android, long-press

I am trying to a make an app that has just one button . When you press it plays a sound and when you LONG press it , It gives you the option to share . The app is working without any errors .. but the share option just wont open . And the button does nothing when you long press it .

```
  package com.example.buttonclicksound;

  import com.example.buttonclicksound.MainActivity;

  import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
  import android.view.Window;
  import android.view.WindowManager;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Button button1;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
AnimationDrawable lightsAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //No title bar is set for the activity
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Full screen is set for the Window
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView lights = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    lightsAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) lights.getDrawable();

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.splash);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

            mPlayer.start();
            mPlayer.setLooping(false);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ButtonListenerActivity", "error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        e);
            }


        }





    });
     button1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                shareIt();
                return true;
            }

            private void shareIt() {
                //sharing implementation here
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("audio/mPlayer");
                }
        });



}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    lightsAnimation.start();

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Its extremly frustrating .. been working so hard at this .. and the Daam thing just wont work .

after some further work .. I am now stuck at this .. the send via box opens up .. i select email .. but all i get is a blank email

```
  private void shareIt(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                //sharing implementation here
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Ringtone      File:"+getResources().getResourceEntryName(mPlayer)+".mp3");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Ringtone File : "+getResources().getResourceEntryName(mPlayer)+".mp3");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.android.soundfiles/"+mPlayer));
sharingIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Ringtone File : "+getResources().getResourceEntryName(mPlayer)+".mp3");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Sound File"));

                }
        });
```

Comment: Did it .. still not working .. also set the View on .. OnLongClickListener()

Comment: button1.setLongClickable(true);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
     
    mPlayer.start();
    mPlayer.setLooping(false);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("ButtonListenerActivity", "error: " + e.getMessage(),
       e);
    }

Comment: button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
          public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
              
              shareIt();
              return true;
          }
          
          private void shareIt() {
     //sharing implementation here
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sharingIntent.setType("audio/mPlayer");
     }
      });

Comment: I get the feedback after the long press .. so the button is working .. I guess it is just not passing the audio file

Comment: Maybe I am missing something with the sharing implementation

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with your sharingIntent, just creating it.

Comment: Did it .. still not working .. also set the View on .. OnLongClickListener()
button1.setLongClickable(true);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
     
    mPlayer.start();
    mPlayer.setLooping(false);
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("ButtonListenerActivity", "error: " + e.getMessage(),
       e);
    }

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer so now it looks confusing. You are not doing anything with your sharingIntent. You just create it, so it just gets garbage collected. You forgot a startActivity or such line.

Comment: I am not trying to start a new activity .. the button has an audio file set to it .. when you click it .. it plays (R.splash) .. I was want it to be able to share it on long press ... When you long press it .. the share option box should pop up .. asking you to share it with which application .. whatsapp , gmail .. etc etc

Comment: If you have an idea ..Can please fix my code and send it ..I am at my wits end over here

Comment: Yeah, but you just create the intent. You're not sending it anywhere. The component which does the sharing never sees your intent.

Comment: You need to add a startActivity(shareIntent) to the sharing method, otherwise no-one will process your intent to share the stuff. It might be missing other things, but you need at least that. See the examples here http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Thanks a ton .. I ll go through the link and get back if i need any help ..Thanks !

Comment: Ohkay .. I modified start(shareIntent) .. but i cant figure out how to move forward .. any way you can help .. the code runs .. i get the share via option .. but the song is not linked .. and all i get is a blank email

Comment: Read the link I gave, the section "Send Binary Content". Good luck.